# Uber universal link doesn't set dropoff location

Tags: android, ios, uber-api

I'm trying to integrate Uber to my map-based website. I need to setPickup with dropoff location. I have generated links like `https://m.uber.com/ul/?action=setPickup&client_id=MY-ID&pickup=my_location&dropoff[latitude]=59.9815498597967&dropoff[longitude]=30.3844866137085&dropoff[nickname]=%D0%92%20%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B5&link_text=%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%20%D0%B7%D0%B0%20%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9!` I have tried this links on my Android (MIUI). They open UBER app but dropoff location doesn't set. How can I test it or what's wrong with links?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just created a deeplink to my own location:

https://m.uber.com/ul/?action=setPickup&client_id=Rd3a2B9JITP.....&pickup[latitude]=37.7749295&pickup[longitude]=-122.4194155&dropoff[latitude]=37.6213129&dropoff[longitude]=-122.3789554&dropoff[nickname]=%D0%92%20%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B5&link_text=%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%20%D0%B7%D0%B0%20%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9!.

This deeplink works for me. Can you try it with your own client_id? I have added pick up location because my real location is not in SF - but  pickup=my_loc‌ation is also fine if it is not against Uber terms related to pickup and destination distance. I also changed destination to be SF.

[image]

It is also working with your location:

https://m.uber.com/ul/?action=setPickup&client_id=Rd3a2B9JITPWPLPz......&pickup[latitude]=59.985569&pickup[longitude]=30.364568&dropoff[latitude]=59.9815498597967&dropoff[longitude]=30.3844866137085&dropoff[nickname]=%D0%92%20%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B5&link_text=%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%20%D0%B7%D0%B0%20%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9!

[image]